# Using FillRect() in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, graphics, gdi

I am new to using Graphics in Visual C++. I am just trying to make a rectangle filled with a color. Need help to correct this...

```
RECT rect;
HDC hdc;
hdc=CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"),NULL,NULL,NULL);
rect.left=30;
rect.right=100;
rect.top=50;
rect.bottom=200;
FillRect(hdc,&rect,(HBRUSH)(RGB(40,151,151)));
```

The error is:

`ERROR: The variable 'rect' is being used without being initialized.`

Comment: Really? I would have thought that would work. Are you sure there isn't another "rect" somewhere that this applies to?

Comment: Is that an error or a warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will normally be a warning, not an error. In this case, it also appears to be spurious.

It *might* work better if you initialize it something like:

```
HDC hdc=CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"),NULL,NULL,NULL);
RECT rect = {30, 50, 100, 200};
HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50, 151, 151));

FillRect(hdc, &rect, brush);

DeleteObject(brush);
```

Do note the use of `CreateSolidBrush` -- casting a color to an HBRUSH seems unlikely to work.

Comment: Thanks, But it is not making the specified rectangle.

Comment: @shubhanksrivastava: It should using the same coordinates you specified. I can't do much if those are wrong though. Truthfully, hard-coded coordinates are nearly always wrong though.

Comment: Also above I guess you meant CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50,151,151));

Answer (score 3):

Your code fails because of this code:

```
(HBRUSH)(RGB(40,151,151))
```

You cannot cast an RGB color to an `HBRUSH` in any meaningful way.  The only way to obtain an `HBRUSH` is a ask the system to give you one.

So, you need to create a real brush using one of the API functions for that purpose. For example, `CreateSolidBrush`.

```
HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(40,151,151));
```

When you have finished with the brush, call `DeleteObject` to return resources to the system.

As a general rule, every time you write a cast, regard the code as very suspicious. Always endeavour to write code without casts.